# Python Backslash errors

Tags: python, xlrd

I'm making a program in python that will copy excel files, rename them according to their contents, and then save them in a different folder.

I'm having problems with backslashes in the code though. Any ideas for how I can make this work?

```
import os
import os.path
import csv
import xlrd
import datetime
import glob
import shutil

def newfilename(name):
    book = xlrd.open_workbook(name)
    sheet = book.sheet_by_index(0)
    name = sheet.cell(6,6).value
    name = name[:10]
    pn = sheet.cell(6,1).value
    date = sheet.cell(4,0).value
    try:
        datenew = datetime.datetime(*xlrd.xldate_as_tuple(date, book.datemode))
        except:
        datenew = "00/00/00"
    print(datenew)
    datenew = str(datenew)
    print(datenew)
    datenew = datenew[:10]
    newpn = ""
    for i in pn:
        try:
            rand = int(i)
            newpn = newpn + str(rand)
        except:
            pass
    return str(newpn+"-"+str(name)+"-PackagingForm-"+datenew)


def excelwriter(old_file_path,new_file_path):
    for subfolder_name in os.listdir(old_file_path):
        print(subfolder_name)
        subfolder_path = os.path.join(old_file_path,subfolder_name)
        print(subfolder_path)
        print(os.listdir(os.path.join(old_file_path,subfolder_path)))
        for file_name in os.listdir(os.path.join(old_file_path,subfolder_path)):
            file_path = os.path.join(subfolder_path,file_name)
            print("file path" +file_path)
            try:
                new_file_name = newfilename(file_path)
            except:
                new_file_name = "NEW" + file_name
            new_file_path = os.path.join(new_file_path,subfolder_name,new_file_name)
            new_file_path.replace(r"\\","/")
            print(str(new_file_path))
            print(str(new_file_path)+".xlsx")
            if file_name[-4:]=="xlsx":
                os.rename(str(file_path),str(new_file_path)+".xlsx")
            elif file_name[-3:]=="xls":
                os.rename(str(file_path),str(new_file_path)+".xls")
            elif file_name[-3:]=="pdf":
                os.rename(str(file_path),str(new_file_path)+".pdf")
            else:
                pass
```

From here, I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#22>", line 1, in <module>
    excelwriter(r'C:\Users\harridr3\Desktop\New Test',r'C:\Users\harridr3\Desktop\New folder')
  File "C:\Users\harridr3\Desktop\python testing\renaming.py", line 52, in excelwriter
    os.rename(str(file_path),str(new_file_path)+".xlsx")
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 3] The system cannot find the path specified: 'C:\\Users\\harridr3\\Desktop\\New folder\\ABL Lights\\2344327-ABL Lights-PackagingForm-00/00/00.xlsx'
```

Comment: `new_file_path.replace(r"\\","/")` I think you need to drop the `r` here.  I'm not sure how this all goes together though.  Also look at [shutil.move](http://docs.python.org/2/library/shutil.html#shutil.move)

Comment: Your problem is that the target directory does not exist, you should try making the directory structure first with `os.makedirs` or similar.

Answer (score 1):

You can't have forward slashes in your file name, it seems to be the source of the error in your code (i assume you don't want several new directories for each new file).

Try:

```
datenew = "00-00-00"
```

Comment: Well, I think technically the forward slashes would be okay, but they're still the cause of the problem because they expect a couple levels of directories that do not exist.

Comment: Yes, it seems you can mix forward and backward slashes for windows paths in python.